# Google OAuth in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET vNext and I don't find how to configure Google OAuth.

I have uncomment the line in Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

But where am I supposed to configure it? I tried to replicate the pattern:

```
services.Configure<MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientSecret"];
});
```

But

```
services.Configure<GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions>
```

Isn't recognized even if the dependency is present in project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample at https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs.

I haven't tried it, but it looks like you configure it using app.UseGoogleAuthentication():

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "560027070069-37ldt4kfuohhu3m495hk2j4pjp92d382.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    options.ClientSecret = "n2Q-GEw9RQjzcRbU3qhfTj8f";
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteError = ctx =>

        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/error?ErrorMessage=" + UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(ctx.Error.Message));
            ctx.HandleResponse();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the configuration store like this

```
Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
```

then what you're also missing (if that's what you mean by 'configure Google OAuth') is the part where you store the values in the SecretManager as described in [the ASP.NET docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html#use-secretmanager-to-store-facebook-appid-and-appsecret) (they use facebook but you can just put whatever keys you want in there). It's a command line tool and it avoids you storing the keys in the code like that. In Google's case you'd probably want to change it to:

```
Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientID"];
Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
```

but it can be whatever you want.